# Is it possible to make a yt to mp4 discord bot?

Tags: discord

This is my first time asking, Is it possible to make a discord bot that converts a youtube video to an mp4 file?

Answer (score -1):

Since this a non-code specific question, yes it is possible to do so. Many music bots either stream the music directly from youtube or download it and play the audio.

If you are using Python you can look at [`pytube3`](https://pypi.org/project/pytube3/) to do so.

Comment: shouldn't questions like this be answered? Since this is not specific and is opinion based

Comment: @I_love_vegetables Your comment doesn't really make sense but it's worth answering it as someone might look for it in the future. The question may be considered off-topic but the answers are on topic for the question

Comment: oh my goodness i meant to say "shouldn't questions like this not be answered?" but thanks for the explanation :D

Comment: Please do not reward questions like this, which are off topic and don't demonstrate even the minimum expected effort, with an answer. Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum and it is better that new users not get any such misconception.